# Экспорт функции в функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему экспорт функции не работает:

```
function converterTime(unitime) {
  var a = new Date(unitime * 1000);
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var year = a.getFullYear();
  var month = months[a.getMonth()];
  var date = a.getDate();
  var hour = a.getHours();
  var min = a.getMinutes();
  var sec = a.getSeconds();
  var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
}

function drawDetailedFriend(data) {
  var user = data.response[0];
  var $detail = $('.detail');
  var unitime = user.last_seen.time
  converterTime(unitime);
  var online = user.online ? 'Online' : 'offline';
  let isOnlineClass = user.online ? 'is-online1' : 'is-offline1';
  var ulHtml = '<li>' + 'Информация:' + '</li>' + '<li>' + 'ID:' + ' ' + user.id + '</li>' + '<li class="bee">' + time + '</li>'


  $detail.find('img').attr('src', user.photo_big);
  $detail.find('h3').text(user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name);
  $detail.find('ul').html(ulHtml);
  $detail.find('button').attr('data-id', user.id);

  $detail.show();
}
```

Пишет: `friends.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: time is not defined`

Comment: ошибка friends.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: time is not defined

Comment: Так тут не  передача не работает - у вас просто `last_seen` null вот и всё

Comment: нет я просто скрипт не полностью скинул...

Comment: все работает если в одной функции вместе но так не читабельно и мне надо розделить

Comment: Значит вы пытаетесь манипулировать переменной time из другой функции в текущей.... а её, нет, понятно дело

Comment: как исправить??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы работать с результатами другой функции:

1. Надо возвращать это значение в первой функции
2. В текущей брать его результат и складывать в переменную и потом манипулировать

```js
function converterTime(unitime){
    var a = new Date(unitime * 1000);
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var year = a.getFullYear();
    var month = months[a.getMonth()];
    var date = a.getDate();
    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    var sec = a.getSeconds();
    var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec ;
    
    ////////////////////////////////
    return time;  // <!------------
    ////////////////////////////////
}

function drawDetailedFriend(data) {

    var user = data.response[0];
    var $detail = $('.detail');
    var unitime = user.last_seen.time
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    let time = converterTime(unitime); // <!-------
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    var online = user.online ? 'Online' : 'offline';
    let isOnlineClass = user.online ? 'is-online1' : 'is-offline1';
    var ulHtml = '<li>'+'Информация:'+'</li>' + '<li>'+ 'ID:' + ' ' + user.id+'</li>' + '<li class="bee">'+time+'</li>'


    $detail.find('img').attr('src', user.photo_big);
    $detail.find('h3').text(user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name);
    $detail.find('ul').html(ulHtml);
    $detail.find('button').attr('data-id', user.id);

    $detail.show(); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает!!!

Comment: @Назар галочку тык :)